# How to Convert Quarterly Data into Annual Data

Tags: time-series, dataset, macroeconomics

I'm doing a project where I'm trying to compare the median wage of workers that had federal job training to the minimum wage indexed to productivity. The Department of Labor only offers the median earnings data of these workers throughout the diffrent quarters, but the baseline wage I'm comparing too (i.e. the minimum wage indexed to productivity) is only available on a yearly basis. I've attached the DOL website where I intend to get the worker data and the other website that has the baseline data. I'm just trying to get these two to line up so I can plot a nice time series. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

https://www.epi.org/publication/raising-the-federal-minimum-wage-to-15-by-2024-would-lift-pay-for-nearly-40-million-workers/

https://www.doleta.gov/performance/results/WIA_Performance_Results.cfm